# Show that $2^{2^{n+1}-1} +1 \le 2^{2^n}$

Tags: induction

I tried an inductive proof but it didn't work out and I'm stuck for ideas.

Comment: When $n=0$, the left hand side is $3$, and the right is $2$. When $n=1$, the left hand side is $9$, and the right is $4$. Etc. What you are trying to prove is false.

Answer (score 1):

This is false, in general: For we have

$$2^{2^{n + 1} - 1} = 2^{2^{n} \cdot 2 - 1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(2^{2^n}\right)^2 > 2^{2^n}$$

for every $n \ge 1$.